# Keeping multiple values under a single key in dictionary

Tags: java, android

In dictionary object , There's is a key named cityName . Under this single key , I would like to keep many values . How should I do this. I'm really sorry if my question bother you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the following ways:

**1) `HashMap` within a `HashMap`**

```
HashMap dict = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>();
```

**2) `List` within a `HashMap`**

```
HashMap dict = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
```

**3) Custom Object within the `HashMap`**

So you define a new class `MyContainer`, that will have properties to store all the different items. Then put this object inside the `HashMap`

```
 HashMap dict = new HashMap<String,MyContainer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is an obsolete class. You should try using Map.

You could create a HashMap in which the value type is a List of some type, por example:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Hope it helps.